# Force open A Selectpicker Programmatically by Javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am currently developing an asp.net web app where I use a lot of drop down lists populated from a database. To give the the user the ability to  search through these lists, I use bootstrap `Selectpicker` with search mode. Recently I had to force open a select picker in client side automatically after the user click a button.
I tried many different codes from many places but it seems to only works with the normal select.

Is there a specific way to force a select picker to expand on a button click?

```
<select id="MyList01" class="selectpicker show-tick" data-live-search="true"
        data-style="btn-default" runat="server">
```

Comment: Provide your question with a code samples please

Answer (score 1):

`selectpicker` will change your the normal select html element to custom element

```
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select open " >
<button ype="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn-default" 
        data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="MyList01" .... > xxxx</button> ...
 ....
 </div>
```

So in order to trigger an event to this drop down list you have to select that rendered button and trigger the event on it by the below code

```
$('[data-id="MyList01"]').click();
```